# 404 in Nginx server after moving Magento Multistore from sub-domain to sub-folder

Tags: nginx, directory

We have a Magento multistore with 3 stores.
We need to move one store that is in subdomain to a sub-folder of another domain: From **MyShop.MyDomain1.com** to **MyDomain1.es/MyShop/**

We need to make this change without creating physically a folder /MyShop in the server (keeping the multistore Magento).

*The first step:*

What we did is going to the Magento settings, General-> Web and change unsecure and secure sections, like this image:
[unsecure and secure sections capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ueoxu.jpg)

*The second step:*

Is to adjust the web server. We work with **Nginx**.
We have not changed the vhost domain of MyDomain1.com.

And we have point the root of the MyDomain1.es to the multistore Magento directory:

```
/*************************VHOST MyDomain1.es**************************/
server {
        listen *:80;

        server_name  mydomain1.es www.mydomain1.es;

        root   /var/www/mydomain1.com/web/;

        client_max_body_size 20M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

        error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mydomain1.es/error.log notice;
        access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mydomain1.es/access.log combined;

    location ~ /\.git {
    deny all;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html; 
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
       #try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handlerhandler
}

        location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }


       location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
            access_log        off;
            log_not_found     off;
            expires           360d;
        }

        ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
        location ^~ /app/                { allow 127.0.0.1; deny all; }
        location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
        location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
        location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
        location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
        location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }
        location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
                auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
                auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
                autoindex            on;
        }

       location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
                rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
                rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }
        location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
                if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

                expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9023;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $storecode; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
                fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
                include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

                fastcgi_connect_timeout 15m;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 15m;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 15m;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_next_upstream error invalid_header timeout http_500;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "max_input_vars=5000"; ## Limite de 1000 productos en tienda

                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 32k;
        }

         }

        location ^~ /awstats-icon {
            alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
        }
}

/************************************************************/
```

When we visit the store the web theme (skin, js, menu, footer...) works well, but all pages shows Magento cms 404 error, in MyDomain1.es/MyShop and MyDomain1.es

Please, someone has had the same problem?
We have something wrong in settings Nginx?

We appreciate any help. Thanks in advance